# Why should I use the exists() function for pattern existence?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

These two hypothetical Cypher queries produces the same result:

```
MATCH(s:Start)
WHERE exists((s)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(:End))
RETURN s
```

and

```
MATCH(s:Start)
WHERE (s)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(:End)
RETURN s
```

The only difference is that the second query has no call to the [exists()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-exists) function, but semantically these two queries are equals. Right?

So, why and when should I use the `exists()` function passing a pattern as parameter?

**EDIT:**

I Noticed some differences in the output of `PROFILE`:

```
PROFILE MATCH(s:Start)
WHERE exists((s)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(:End))
RETURN s
+------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Operator         | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Variables | Other                                         |
+------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults  |              2 |    1 |       0 | s         | s                                             |
| |                +----------------+------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+
| +Filter          |              2 |    1 |       5 | s         | NestedExpression(Filter-Expand(All)-Argument) |
| |                +----------------+------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan |              3 |    3 |       4 | s         | :Start                                        |
+------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 9

PROFILE MATCH(s:Start)
WHERE (s)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(:End)
RETURN s

+------------------+----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Operator         | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Variables               | Other                   |
+------------------+----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| +ProduceResults  |              2 |    1 |       0 | s                       | s                       |
| |                +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| +SemiApply       |              2 |    1 |       0 | s                       |                         |
| |\               +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| | +Filter        |              1 |    0 |       1 | anon[29], anon[47], s   | anon[47]:End            |
| | |              +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| | +Expand(All)   |              1 |    1 |       4 | anon[29], anon[47] -- s | (s)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->() |
| | |              +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| | +Argument      |              3 |    3 |       0 | s                       |                         |
| |                +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan |              3 |    3 |       4 | s                       | :Start                  |
+------------------+----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+

Total database accesses: 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used in the WHERE clause, they should be semantically equal, but there are cases where exists() is needed outside of the WHERE clause.

One example is when you want a boolean to represent if the pattern exists.

```
MATCH (s:Start)
RETURN exists((s)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(:End)) as connectedToEnd
```

Comment: I noticed some differences in the output of `PROFILE` of these queries (see my edit). The query with `exists()` has a more compact execution plan.